# How to use setOnClickListener with resource position?

Tags: java, android, button

I created a button called save, when clicked on the button it saves some information via `SharedPreferences`.

But I would like to save more than one information in different positions, because the way my code is, every time I write it replaces the existing information by being in the same position, to solve this in `editor.putString` I should do the following:

```
Editor.putString ("coordinates" + position, detailsText.getText (). ToString () + "\ n" +Share coordinates + "\ n \ n" + addressComplete);
```

I can not include the position in editor.putString ("coordinates" + position ...

Is there any alternative so that I can use the button with the position?

My Code:

```
salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       // Save to shared preferences

       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("arquivoPreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
       editor.putString("coordinates", detailsText.getText().toString() + "\n" + coordenadasShare + "\n\n" + enderecoCompleto);
       editor.commit();

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coordenadas salvas com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get button location:

```
view.getLocationInWindow()
or
view.getLocationOnScreen()
```